# How to write the function isSymbol in scala?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write the function isFunction in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422352/how-to-write-the-function-isfunction-in-scala)

How can i write a isSymbol function in scala, so that this works:

```
def isSymbol(x:Any) = /* SomeCode */

println(isSymbol('aSimbol)) //true
println(isSymbol("not a simbol")) //false
```

Comment: Well you start by filling in the block that says `/* SomeCode */`.

Comment: Define what you mean by symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about [scala.Symbol](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Symbol):

```
def isSymbol(x:Any) = x.isInstanceOf[Symbol]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection (Scala 2.10M4), this can be done as follows (simply to show the idea, the solution provided by @ChrisJamesC is much simpler for the given case):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Flag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ currentMirror => cm }

object Check {
  def isSymbol(x: Any): Boolean = {
    cm.reflect(x).symbol.asType =:= typeOf[Symbol]
  }
}
```