# How to write the function isFunction in scala?

Tags: scala

How can i write a isFunction function in scala, so that this works:

```
def isFunction(x:Any) = /* SomeCode */

println(isFunction(isFunction _)) //true
println(isFunction("not a function")) //false
```

Comment: Btw, since you also asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422391/how-to-write-the-function-iscaseobject-in-scala and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422293/how-to-write-the-function-issymbol-in-scala: do you happen to have a weakly-typed background, e.g., Python?

Comment: A better question would be, how can I avoid having to use methods that take `Any` as an argument, with a description of what you're trying to do. If you think you need such a thing, usually you're doing something wrong.

Comment: As the old OO adage say: tell, don't ask. Let the object worry about what it is and how it does it's things and, as Luigi says, don't use `Any`.

Comment: I actually do know it is not "good idiomatic scala", but i am rewriting the examples from "The Little Schemer" in Scala, in both scheme (to resemble the book) and scala (to resemble good code) "idioms".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite ugly, but it works:

```
def isFunction(x:Any) = x match {
  case _: Function0[_] => true
  case _: Function1[_, _] => true
  case _: Function2[_, _, _] => true
  ...
  case _: Function22[...] => true
  case _: PartialFunction[_, _] => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pedrofurla. I also added ``PartialFunction``.

Answer (score 1):

In scala you can view Functions as just objects that have a public `apply` method. I am not familiar with the new scala 2.10 reflection api, but you can always use traditional java way as:

```
def isFunction(x:Any) = x.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).exists{name => 
  name == "apply" || name.startsWith("apply$")
}

val set = Set(1, 2)
val str = "abc"
val func = { _:Int=> 1 }
val map = Map(1 -> 2)
val tuple = 1->2
val obj = new { def apply = 1 }
val obj2 = new { private def apply = 2 } 

assert(isFunction(set))
assert(!isFunction(str))
assert(isFunction(func))
assert(isFunction(map))
assert(!isFunction(tuple))
assert(isFunction(obj))
assert(!isFunction(obj2))
```

Comment: functions are objects, yes. But not all objects with an apply-method are functions.

Comment: More often we don't care about what the definition signature of an object is but what it does/behaves. Scala itself take objects that have an `unapply` method as an `Extractor` in pattern match. It also  has "view bounds" and that is exactly why I said 'view Functions as'.  This solution may be conceptually incorrect (in fact that depends on what you call a `function`) but it does handle the situations that you have more than 22 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a special fan of your solution and I agree with Daniel Sobral comment. If I had to implement it I would do that in a type safe way, through implicit conversion

```
trait IsFunctionable {
  def isFunction : Boolean
}

object IsFunctionable {

  object IsFunction extends IsFunctionable {
    def isFunction = true
  }

  object IsNotFunction extends IsFunctionable {
    def isFunction = false
  }

  implicit def function0ToIsFunctionable[A<:Function0[_]](a:A):IsFunctionable = IsFunction
  implicit def function1ToIsFunctionable[A<:Function1[_,_]](a:A):IsFunctionable = IsFunction
  implicit def function2ToIsFunctionable[A<:Function2[_,_,_]](a:A):IsFunctionable = IsFunction
  // and so on

  implicit def anyToIsFunctionable[A](a:A):IsFunctionable = IsNotFunction
}
```

And now you can happily test in the repl:

```
scala>  import IsFunctionable._
import IsFunctionable._

scala>  val a: Int => Int = _ * 2
a: Int => Int = <function1>

scala>  val b: (Int,Int) => Int = (_*_)
b: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala>  a(3)
res0: Int = 6
scala>  b(2,4)
res3: Int = 8

scala>  a.isFunction
res4: Boolean = true

scala>  b.isFunction
res5: Boolean = true

scala>  "Hello".isFunction
res6: Boolean = false
```