# How to write the function isCaseObject in scala?

Tags: scala

How can i write a isCaseObject function in scala, so that this works:

```
def isCaseObject(x:Any) = /* Some Code */

case object aCaseObject
println(isCaseObject(aCaseObject)) //true
println(isCaseObject("not a case object")) //false
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using reflection (Scala 2.10M4), this can be done as follows:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Flag
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ currentMirror => cm }

object Check {

  def isCaseObject(x:Any): Boolean = {
    cm.reflect(x).symbol.hasFlag(Flag.CASE)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

All case classes extend Product, so you can use the type system:

```
 def isCC[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:< Product) = a
```

If you try and call it with a not Product:

```
scala> isCC("test")
<console>:17: error: Cannot prove that java.lang.String <:< Product.
              isCC("test")
```

But you can call it with a case class:

```
scala> case class CA(a: Int)
defined class CA

scala> isCC(CA(1))
res19: CA = CA(1)
```

Comment: Although this doesn't prove that it *is*, just that it *can be*.

Comment: it only proves that it is a Product, there is no exclusive type for case classes